# Combine data from 3 google sheets and create a control to select which dataset

Tags: looker-studio

I have a some data across three tabs of a [google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13hcQBIwpLJF_rGOA5Mu21oAoiCTWog_hXmlPx6eVKO4/edit?usp=sharing) which is formatted something like this:

**Sheet 1:**

| Store | Fiscal Year | Date | Category | Sub Category | Debit | Credit | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Store1 | FY 2022 | 1/5/2022 | Fruit | Apples | $50.00 |  | Buy pallet of apples |
| Store1 | FY 2022 | 4/5/2022 | Fruit | Apples |  | $100.00 | Sell half pallet of apples |
| Store1 | FY 2022 | 5/6/2022 | Meat | Pork | $100.00 |  | Buy dressed pig |
| Store1 | FY 2022 | 5/6/2022 | Fruit | Peaches | $75.00 |  | Buy pallet of peaches |
| Store1 | FY 2023 | 7/7/2022 | Meat | Pork |  | $28.99 | Sell 10 pork chops |
| Store1 | FY 2023 | 7/7/2022 | Meat | Pork |  | $106.99 | Sell pork loin |

**Sheet 2:**

| Store | Fiscal Year | Date | Category | Sub Category | Debit | Credit | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Store2 | FY 2022 | 1/5/2022 | Fruit | Peaches | $80.00 |  | Buy pallet of peaches |
| Store2 | FY 2022 | 3/5/2022 | Fruit | Peaches |  | $120.00 | Sell half pallet of peaches |
| Store2 | FY 2022 | 8/6/2022 | Fruit | Peaches |  | $60.00 | Sell rest of peaches at discount |
| Store2 | FY 2023 | 8/7/2022 | Vegetables | Lettuce | $64.12 |  | Buy 100 lettuce |
| Store2 | FY 2023 | 9/7/2022 | Vegetables | Lettuce |  | $14.99 | Sell 12 lettuce |

**Sheet 3**

| Store | Fiscal Year | Date | Category | Sub Category | Debit | Credit | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Store3 | FY 2022 | 1/5/2022 | Fruit | Bananas | $60.00 |  | Buy pallet of bananas |
| Store3 | FY 2022 | 2/5/2022 | Meat | Beef | $150.00 |  | Buy dressed cow |
| Store3 | FY 2022 | 5/6/2022 | Meat | Pork | $100.00 |  | Buy dressed pig |
| Store3 | FY 2022 | 5/6/2022 | Fruit | Beef |  | $800.00 | Sell entire cow |
| Store3 | FY 2023 | 7/7/2022 | Meat | Pork |  | $450.00 | Sell entire pig |
| Store3 | FY 2023 | 7/7/2022 | Meat | Bananas |  | $40.00 | Sell quarter pallet bananas |

You get the picture - one sheet per store, and a column in each sheet which has the Store Name in it.

Traditionally I would be able to merge all these data sets together in a new sheet/table:

| Store | Fiscal Year | Date | Category | Sub Category | Debit | Credit | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Store3 | FY 2022 | 1/5/2022 | Fruit | Bananas | $60.00 |  | Buy pallet of bananas |
| Store3 | FY 2022 | 2/5/2022 | Meat | Beef | $150.00 |  | Buy dressed cow |
| Store3 | etc. |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Store2 | FY 2022 | 1/5/2022 | Fruit | Peaches | $80.00 |  | Buy pallet of peaches |
| Store2 | FY 2022 | 3/5/2022 | Fruit | Peaches |  | $120.00 | Sell half pallet of peaches |
| Store2 | etc. |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Store1 | FY 2022 | 1/5/2022 | Fruit | Apples | $50.00 |  | Buy pallet of apples |
| Store1 | FY 2022 | 4/5/2022 | Fruit | Apples |  | $100.00 | Sell half pallet of apples |
| Store1 | etc. |  |  |  |  |  |  |

With this above merged data, I would then build [reports](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/547ddfe9-fe4c-495e-9d58-c4231bcc8ef5) or pivot tables, and can filter on the `Store` column in order to show data from a single store, multiple stores, or all stores.

I would like to do the same with Google Data Studio - without the manual process of merging the data into a new sheet/table - but I'm struggling with how to:

- blend the data sources correctly
- add a control / filter to be able to drill down to a single store

**Edit**
As suggested, I've created a dummy data set and datastudio report, both editable, to try to illustrate what I'm getting at:

- Dummy Data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13hcQBIwpLJF_rGOA5Mu21oAoiCTWog_hXmlPx6eVKO4/edit?usp=sharing
- Data Studio Report: https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/547ddfe9-fe4c-495e-9d58-c4231bcc8ef5

Comment: Thanks for the direction @Nimantha, I've fleshed out the initial question as suggested and created dummy data and a sample datastudio report.
I am however stumped to as how to properly blend the data - every attempt is immediately missing certain fields or data

Comment: Note that the Google Data Studio report is currently not shared (clicking on it leads to a page that states "*Can't access report*". Ensure that it's set to publicly editable. The rest of the details look fine...Also, if you could post an image along with adding some details on one of the attempts, that would also flesh things out

Comment: Hmm. Please refresh, I've re-set the sharing settings

Comment: Hi @Nimantha Any idea on how to deal with such scenario. I am looking for a solution to this as well.

Comment: @rockinfreakshow: Will have a look during the week